# Kafkacat: how to delete a topic or all its messages?

Tags: apache-kafka, kcat

I am looking for a way to delete a topic or all its messages using `kafkacat`.
Is it possible or the only way is through the script listed [here](https://gist.github.com/filipefigcorreia/3db4c7e525581553e17442792a2e7489)?

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --delete --topic mytopic
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no delete topic feature at this stage in kafkacat according to man page and github source code. So the only way is to use kafka-topics script.

[github source code](https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat/blob/master/)

[man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/kafkacat.1.html)

> kafkacat is a generic non-JVM producer and consumer for Apache Kafka
>   0.8, think of it as a
>        netcat for Kafka.
>
> ```
>  In producer mode ( -P ), kafkacat reads messages from stdin, delimited with a configurable
>  delimeter and produces them to the provided Kafka cluster, topic and partition. In consumer
>  mode ( -C ), kafkacat reads messages from a topic and partition and prints them to stdout
>  using the configured message delimiter.
>
>  If neither -P or -C are specified kafkacat attempts to figure out the mode automatically
>  based on stdin/stdout tty types.
>
>  kafkacat also features a metadata list mode ( -L ), to display the current state of the
>  Kafka cluster and its topics and partitions.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

As @Naween Banuka pointed out, you can also use zookeeper-shell.sh or zkCli.sh (found under zookeeper/bin) to do this:

List the existing topics : `./zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:2181  ls /brokers/topics`

Remove Topic : `./zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:2181  rmr /brokers/topics/yourtopic`

Answer (score -5):

Yes, It's possible.

But first, You have to enable topic deletion on all brokers.
change `delete.topic.enable` to `true`. 
By default, it's `false` (In `server.properties` file)

Then, 
Use topic delete command.

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --delete --topic mytopic
```

If you want to delete that topic permanently, 
You can use the zookeeper delete command.

1. List the existing topics : `./zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:2181  ls /brokers/topics`
2. Remove Topic : `./zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:2181  rmr /brokers/topics/yourtopic`

Comment: I just want to show why you got minuses. The question is "Could I delete topic **another way** than `kafka-topics.sh`?". And your answer is "Yes, it's `kafka-topics.sh`".

Comment: But you guys missed the second part  `zookeeper-shell.sh`